# Scriptable objects only work in the editor, and don't work when I build

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

When I launch my game in the Unity editor, my scriptable objects work :
This part of my script :

```
skinsbgcreator[] doges = new skinsbgcreator[Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(skinsbgcreator)).Length];
doges = Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll(typeof(skinsbgcreator)) as skinsbgcreator[];
```

gives me an array of 6 instances of my scriptable object `skinsbgcreator`.

But when I build the game for iOS, this part of the script don't work anymore : it's like if the instances vanished. This array is empty.

So please do you know what could be the reason ? Tell me if you need more informations

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure all assemblies were rebuilt (with final types).
Try to Load assembly containing all required types explicite before.